# Add classes to html element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, containers, expand

I want to expand a container with use of jQuery.

For some reason, and I can't see why, it doens't work...

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
    $(".viewPrices").click(function () {
    $(".list",this).addClass("visible");
}, function () {
    $(".list",this).removeClass("visible");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2sQ/)

**
Actually works with:

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
$(".list").addClass("visible");
});
```

But I would like to remove the class when the button is clicked once more

**

Comment: TRY : http://jsfiddle.net/2N2sQ/1/

Comment: Have you read the [`.click()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)? (Hint: how many arguments does it accept, and what are their types?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no Second parameter To [jQuery Click Event](http://api.jquery.com/click/)**

You can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for Hide/Show and [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) For toggling Class

**Example For Class Toggle**

```
 $(".viewPrices").click(function () {
    $(".list",this).toggleClass("visible");
});
```

**Example For Toggle Display**

```
 $(".viewPrices").click(function () {
    $(".list",this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Haha I put toggleClass there 2 times, but ofc only one time is need.. Thx pal.. better make myself some more coffee ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) if you want to switch the visiblility

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
    $(".list",this).toggle();
});
```

You do not need to pass current object in context as div with id list is not descendant of the button if you do not have multiple html structures like you have in fiddle then you can directly access element with class list

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2sQ/3/)**

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
    $(".list").toggle();
});
```

You can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) if you want to switch class

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
    $(".list",this).toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Comment: Maybe he needs to add the class rather than just applying the visibility.

Comment: @Alvaro there is toggleClass too :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea yeah, I know it, just pointing it out as this might not be the solution he is looking for.

Comment: @Adil did you forget the class inside `toggleClass`?

Comment: toggleClass doesnt work... Check the fiddle, both toggleClass, addClass and removeClass doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
$(".visible").removeClass("visible");
$(".list").addClass("visible");

});
```

Comment: Actually works with:

$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
$(".list").addClass("visible");
});

But I would like to remove the class when u click the button once more :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
   $(".list").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".viewPrices").click(function () {
     $(".list").toggle("visible");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleSearch(obj) {
 if (obj.className == "viewPrices")
{
document.getElementById("viewPrices").style.display = "none";
obj.className = "";
}else {
 document.getElementById("viewPrices").style.display = "block";
  obj.className = "viewPrices";

}
  return false;
}
```